# Satan and language

Tags: satan, demons

How developed is satan’s ability to use human languages? Can he construct new words? Can he write a novel or scientific paper? How can one identify devil or demonic writings other than using the Bible?

Comment: What stops satan from, instead of using the larynx of the human he enters, using their hands and scribble something down?

Comment: This question is pure speculation and will only attract opinion-based answers - which is not allowed. What research have you done into this subject and upon what findings do you suppose that devils or demons have the ability to use language to write?

Comment: I’m asking if anyone have done this kind of research.

Comment: And right is declared in Deuteronomy?

Comment: Asking if anyone has done this research might be OK.  It would be better if you identified the faith tradition within Christianity that you would accept answers from.  It's not that the rightness of the answer depends on the authority, it's that the appropriateness of the answer depends on the authority.

Comment: Appropriate? Excuse me, i do not understand this word. I’m interested in truth, not politics.

Comment: @Helena Appropriate, because if you want an answer from let's say protestant doctrine, you may not be satisfied if you get an answer from catholic tradition, or from Jehovas Witnesses' doctrine, or from the Book of Mormon. This site is a Q&A site about what the various christian denominations teach, not about what is The Truth. That is why many if not most questions that don't specify which denomination is being asked are off-topic, simply because they aren't really answerable objectively.

Answer (score 1):

Satan does not write anything, he has no body to do so. People write things. Judging by the things people write, the ability to use human language for evil is pretty big.

As a sidenote, the only mention of writings that were written by some heavenly or demonic being is (and that were actually on earth, not in some vision), as far as I am aware:

- the stone plates given to Moses
- the writing on the wall in Daniel

While there are mentions of books in visions and such, there seem to be no other mention of writings, on earth, done by heavenly of demonic beings.